# Unable to copy audio disc with Brasero

Tags: sound, cd, brasero, cd-ripping

It seems it creates the image correctly. After I insert the blank cd I get:

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao getting varg
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroCdrdao got varg:
BraseroCdrdao stopping
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroCdrdao output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_OSAF0X.bin toc = /tmp/brasero_tmp_OSAF0X.toc
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroCdrdao getting varg
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_image_output
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_use_average_rate
BraseroCdrdao got varg:
    cdrdao
    read-cd
    --device
    /dev/sr0
    --read-raw
    --datafile
    /tmp/brasero_tmp_OSAF0X.bin
    -v
    2
    /tmp/brasero_tmp_OSAF0X.toc
BraseroCdrdao Launching command
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroCdrdao stderr: WARNING: Environment variable 'HOME' not defined- cannot read .cdrdao.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Cdrdao version 1.2.3 - (C) Andreas Mueller <andreas@daneb.de>
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: /dev/sr0: HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GU70N  Rev: A102
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Using driver: Generic SCSI-3/MMC - Version 2.0 (options 0x0000)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Reading toc and track data...
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Track   Mode    Flags  Start                Length
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: ------------------------------------------------------------
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  1      AUDIO   0      00:00:00(     0)     03:54:30( 17580)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  2      AUDIO   0      03:54:30( 17580)     03:18:17( 14867)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  3      AUDIO   0      07:12:47( 32447)     04:33:01( 20476)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  4      AUDIO   0      11:45:48( 52923)     03:00:23( 13523)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  5      AUDIO   0      14:45:71( 66446)     03:46:36( 16986)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  6      AUDIO   0      18:32:32( 83432)     02:27:71( 11096)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  7      AUDIO   0      21:00:28( 94528)     02:30:53( 11303)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  8      AUDIO   0      23:31:06(105831)     03:31:68( 15893)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr:  9      AUDIO   0      27:02:74(121724)     03:21:26( 15101)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 10      AUDIO   0      30:24:25(136825)     03:43:35( 16760)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 11      AUDIO   0      34:07:60(153585)     02:48:62( 12662)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 12      AUDIO   0      36:56:47(166247)     02:38:16( 11866)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 13      AUDIO   0      39:34:63(178113)     03:20:38( 15038)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 14      AUDIO   0      42:55:26(193151)     04:13:38( 19013)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 15      AUDIO   0      47:08:64(212164)     03:38:45( 16395)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 16      AUDIO   0      50:47:34(228559)     03:33:54( 16029)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 17      AUDIO   0      54:21:13(244588)     03:31:65( 15890)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Leadout AUDIO   0      57:53:03(260478)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: PQ sub-channel reading (audio track) is supported, data format is BCD.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Raw P-W sub-channel reading (audio track) is supported.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Cooked R-W sub-channel reading (audio track) is supported.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Copying audio tracks 1-17: start 00:00:00, length 57:53:03 to "/tmp/brasero_tmp_OSAF0X.bin"...
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Track 1...
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 00:00:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Found ISRC code.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 00:01:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 00:02:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 57:51:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 57:52:00
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Found 552 Q sub-channels with CRC errors.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Found CD-TEXT data.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Found disk catalogue number.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Reading of toc and track data finished successfully.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao stderr: HUP
BraseroCdrdao process finished with status 0
BraseroCdrdao Finished successfully session
BraseroCdrdao stopping
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_done_tracks
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroCdrdao Automatically adding track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_image_output
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_add_track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_Z6XR0X.bin toc = /tmp/brasero_tmp_Z6XR0X.toc
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao getting varg
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao got varg:
BraseroCdrdao deactivating
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao getting varg
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_bus_target_lun
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_speed
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_use_average_rate
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroCdrdao got varg:
    cdrdao
    write
    --device
    /dev/sr0
    -n
    -v
    2
    --simulate
    --speed
    24
    /tmp/brasero_tmp_OSAF0X.toc
BraseroCdrdao Launching command
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroCdrdao stderr: WARNING: Environment variable 'HOME' not defined- cannot read .cdrdao.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Cdrdao version 1.2.3 - (C) Andreas Mueller <andreas@daneb.de>
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: /dev/sr0: HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GU70N  Rev: A102
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Using driver: Generic SCSI-3/MMC - Version 2.0 (options 0x0000)
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Starting write simulation at speed 24...
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Process can be aborted with QUIT signal (usually CTRL-\).
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: WARNING: No super user permission to setup real time scheduling.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Turning BURN-Proof on
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Enabling JustLink.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Info fld=-11634, Current 
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: SCSI command failed: sense key: 0x03: Medium Error
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Additional sense indicates: Write error
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: Raw sense data: 0xf0 0x00 0x03 0xff 0xff 0xd2 0x8e 0x0a 0x00 0x00 
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: 0x00 0x00 0x0c 0x00 0x00 0x00 
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: ERROR: Write data failed.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: ERROR: Simulation failed.
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroCdrdao stderr: HUP
BraseroCdrdao process finished with status 1
BraseroCdrdao called brasero_job_error
BraseroCdrdao finished with an error
BraseroCdrdao asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 0
    message = "no message"
BraseroCdrdao stopping
Session error : unknown (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2859)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall brasero brasero-cdrkit brasero-common cdrdao cdparanoia cue2toc dvdauthor dvd+rw-tools genisoimage wodim
```

*If the error persists, I suggest change to k3b*